# Rails 4.2.5 - ActiveJob using deliver_now even after specifying deliver_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, rails-activejob

I plan to send mails asynchronously in Rails 4.2.5 using ActionMailer#deliver_later.

The AppMailer file uses 'mail' to send across the mail & I am using deliver_later as follows:

```
AppMailer.project_created_support_mail(@project).deliver_later
```

However, logs show that the argument passed still is 'deliver_now'

```
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [b341ea8c-ca96-4a4e-8079-572925864352] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) with arguments: "AppMailer", "project_created_support_mail", "deliver_now"
```

I am assuming there isn't an explicit need to attach a queue like Sidekiq or Resque.

Can someone please help in understanding what I am missing here?

EDIT: The original problem I am facing is that the action to send mail takes ~5 seconds with or without deliver_later. In an attempt to debug the issue, I found out that the argument is still 'deliver_now' (logs above). As pointed out by @torrocus below, 'deliver_now' is called inside the queue. However, the issue that deliver_later takes ~5 seconds still remains.

Comment: If it is in production or similar, have you restarted the server?

Comment: try restarting your server.

Comment: I am currently trying it on dev. The problem is it takes ~5 seconds to deliver the mail with or without deliver_later

Answer (score 1):

When you call `#deliver_later` method you put the job into the queue Active Job. Inside the queue it calls `#deliver_now`.
[deliver_later (ActionMailer::MessageDelivery)](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery/deliver_later)

In development I propose to use gem [mailcatcher](https://rubygems.org/gems/mailcatcher)

Comment: Thanks! That explains the log. However, every mail is taking ~5 seconds to deliver with or without deliver_later. Any idea why?

Comment: Sending emails will always take some time. Email is **asynchronous**. It is suggested to perform such processes in separate queues so as not to block the application. The user should not wait to send an email.

Comment: Isn't that the point of deliver_later? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Not exactly. 
`deliver_later` - email will be delivered through Active Job.
`deliver_now` - delivers an email, but you should remember this protocol does not work in real time